# How to pass the nth optional argument without passing prior arguments in JavaScript functions?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

So imagine we got a function like below, and I want to use the default value for the first parameter `a` and a custom value for second parameter `b`.

```
const func = (a = 1 , b = 2) => {
    console.log("a is equal to " + a, " and b is equal to " + b)
}
```

I want to just pass one value for parameter b. something like this:

```
func(b : 7);
// I want it to print: a is equal to 1 and b is equal to 7
```

How can I achieve it in JavaScript?

Comment: If you don't want to change the function signature, you would need to call it like so `func(undefined, 7)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You modify your function to receive an object and then inside that object you can also define default values for some properties like a and b.

```js
const func = ({ a = 1, b = 2 }) => {
  console.log("a is equal to " + a, " and b is equal to " + b)
}

func({b: 3})
```

Comment: So how about methods like `server.listen(port, hostname, backlog, callback)`? all its parameters are optional.

Comment: Unless the function can receive an object where you can specify name of the parameter you want to pass there is no way to use named parameters.

Answer (score 0):

try to use RORO pattern, to pass object into function