# Pass the last parameter to function - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

If I have a function with two different parameters, how can I make it so that if I input only one parameter, it will use the input as the second parameter rather than the first parameter?
For example, if I have this function:

```
function x(a=1,b=2) {
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
}
```

and call `x(3)`, it will use the 3 for `a` and return "3, 2"

```
x(3);

=> 3
   2
```

I want it so that the function instead uses the 3 for the `b` parameter, and therefore returns "1, 3"

```
x(3);
=> 1
   3
```

Comment: While this can technically be done, what is your use case? There is almost certainly a better alternative.

Comment: `x(undefiined, 3)` but if you really want to have any parameter optional, you should probably pass an object.

Comment: Very related: [Set a default parameter value for a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/894860)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass the nth optional argument without passing prior arguments in JavaScript functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57040478/how-to-pass-the-nth-optional-argument-without-passing-prior-arguments-in-javascr)

Comment: Thank you all, but is there any other way to achieve this than passing parameters as object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your method to use a [destructured object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), you can pass an object with just the properties you wish to and default the rest

```js
function x({a=1,b=2} = {}){
  console.log("a",a);
  console.log("b",b);
}

x();
x({a:10})
x({b:20})
```

Comment: `function x({a=1,b=2} = {})` to allow calling `x()` without anything.

Comment: Thank you all, but is there any other way to achieve this than passing parameters as object

Comment: That's like asking if we can define a variable without using `var` or `let`.

Answer (score 0):

Use **object destructuring** approach

```js
let a,b; 

/*
* define variable to avoid overwrite in large application
*/

function x({a=1,b=2} = {}){
  console.log( { a } );
  console.log( { b } );
}

x({b:20}) /* Passed only 'b' here */
```